# Отправить файл отдельным сообщением.

Tags: база-данных, структуры, логика

Снова я :)
Вообщем у меня есть диалоги (ajax), и мне нужно при загрузке файла отправить его в диалог отдельным сообщением.
Но не могу сообразить как это сделать, а точнее как это всё связать.

Пока есть структура бд сообщений:

```
messages:
id | user_id | dialog_id | text | date
```

Comment: Ну хоть намекните :(

Comment: @Евгений  Кузнецов, я вот ничего не понял. При загрузке какого файла? Если имеется в виду "страница", то получается, что вам при загрузке страницы, нужно её же отправить еще в какой-то диалог. Если же это подгружается какой-то удаленный файл, то куда он подгружается и зачем его дублировать еще и в этих диалогах? Окончательную и жирную точку в "*непонимании*", ставит зачем-то приведённая структура таблицы.

В общем, тег вопроса "**логика**" - тут явно лишний.

Comment: @Deonis ну что тут может быть непонятно, есть удаленный файл, будь то картинка или архив, к пример 1 человек хочет поделится этим файлом в диалоге с другим, он загружает его на сервер, и тем самым скрипт должен его принять и вывести в диалоге, чтобы его видели все кто находится в этом диалоге, и могли скачать его себе.

Comment: @Евгений Кузнецов, так загружайте файл, формируйте на него ссылку и выводите её как обычное сообщение.

Comment: Или сделайте таблицу с файлами и свяжите их как многие-ко-многим.